# How to find top point on geom_smooth generated with method = "gam"

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Let's say I have generated a plot with many `geom_points` and `geom_smooth` based on some strata.

I want to add a single black `geom_point` and black dashed line from the `geom_point` down to the x-axis to highlight which toppoint correspond to the x-axis value of each `b$cohort` within `b$vesicles` (used in facet_wrap).

The `geom_smooth`-curve should be generated with this `method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs")`, rather than a loess-curve.

I followed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71162252/adding-the-maximum-peak-value-in-ggplot-for-geom-smoth#_=_) on SO. However, those solutions were for loess-curves and not what I needed.

Code:

```
  ggplot(b, aes(y = conc_e5, x = size, color = cohort, fill = cohort)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 4, stroke = 1) +
  geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs"),
              se = FALSE, size = 2) +
  facet_wrap(~ vesicles) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 400))
```

Expected output:

**Extra:** would it be possible to add a `geom_text` on top each black dot with the exact x-axis value the `geom_point` is located on?

[image]

Data

```
b <- structure(list(conc_e5 = c(33.5, 2, 1.1, 6.4, 1.4, 1, 1.2, 16.9, 
                                1, 30.6, 3.3, 38, 1, 1, 7.1, 0.8, 7.1, 22.3, 1.4, 3.5, 0.9, 1, 
                                1, 3.8, 1.2, 1.1, 0.9, 10.2, 6.2, 3.8, 1.4, 12, 1.3, 1.4, 16.7, 
                                1.7, 5, 38.9, 2.5, 0.9, 1.7, 4.2, 2, 1.9, 2, 2.5, 5.2, 2.3, 1.4, 
                                2.8, 4.2, 7.9, 7.1, 3.8, 1.2, 2.8, 1.7, 1.9, 1.2, 24.8, 2.6, 
                                1.1, 3.8, 4, 6.9, 1, 4.3, 0.9, 1, 1, 6.9, 1.4, 2.8, 6.9, 4.6, 
                                6.1, 11.3, 3.8, 3.2, 1.7, 1.1, 1.2, 0.9, 2.6, 6.8, 0.9, 3.2, 
                                5.1, 1.4, 1.7, 1.7, 2.6, 1.3, 2.5, 8.3, 2.6, 0.9, 1.7, 2.3, 35.9, 
                                1.7, 20.4, 2.6, 1.2, 12.8, 8.5, 5, 9, 12.4, 1, 1.2, 2.8, 1.3, 
                                0.9, 1.7, 2.3, 1.7, 2.6, 15.7, 4, 12, 1.7, 27.3, 3, 6.8, 4, 29.6, 
                                12.4, 3.4, 6.4, 2.8, 3.5, 9.3, 2.6, 3, 8.9, 2, 8.9, 5.6, 6.1, 
                                12.1, 1, 2.6, 1.7, 1.7, 1.6, 1.7, 3.8, 16.1, 2.4), size = c(220, 
                                                                                            277.5, 287.5, 202.5, 304.1, 1193, 521.7, 159.2, 722.5, 137.8, 
                                                                                            228.1, 172.5, 762.5, 420.4, 152.5, 405.6, 162.5, 117.5, 391.2, 
                                                                                            304.1, 432.5, 72.12, 1151, 237.5, 417.5, 37.74, 43.58, 315.3, 
                                                                                            292.5, 58.12, 43.58, 297.5, 272.5, 407.5, 237.5, 52.17, 115.1, 
                                                                                            159.2, 20.47, 307.5, 277.5, 263.4, 232.5, 52.17, 74.76, 52.5, 
                                                                                            111.1, 62.46, 357.5, 283, 122.5, 220, 137.8, 227.5, 485.5, 27.5, 
                                                                                            87.5, 47.5, 532.5, 212.5, 357.5, 557.5, 351.2, 99.7, 133, 357.5, 
                                                                                            197.5, 472.5, 56.07, 54.08, 190.5, 387.5, 405.6, 147.5, 364.1, 
                                                                                            187.5, 204.7, 262.5, 111.1, 39.12, 32.5, 477.5, 32.5, 347.5, 
                                                                                            242.5, 362.5, 252.5, 123.7, 657.5, 83.29, 190.5, 212.5, 1838, 
                                                                                            352.5, 351.2, 83.29, 347.5, 77.5, 45.18, 152.5, 247.5, 107.1, 
                                                                                            227.5, 39.12, 132.5, 232.5, 64.74, 67.5, 177.3, 377.4, 775, 364.1, 
                                                                                            72.12, 42.04, 165, 362.5, 111.1, 96.18, 257.5, 212.2, 82.5, 364.1, 
                                                                                            177.5, 69.57, 217.5, 77.5, 236.4, 77.5, 57.5, 183.8, 252.5, 326.8, 
                                                                                            377.4, 312.5, 115.1, 152.5, 96.18, 187.5, 332.5, 177.5, 148.1, 
                                                                                            562.5, 272.5, 327.5, 132.5, 83.29, 102.5, 212.2, 283, 217.5), 
                    cohort = c("5C", "ALL", "5C", "ALL", "ALL", "ALL", "5C", 
                               "5C", "ALL", "5C", "KMA", "5C", "ALL", "ALL", "ALL", "KMA", 
                               "ALL", "5C", "ALL", "KMA", "5C", "ALL", "ALL", "ALL", "5C", 
                               "5C", "5C", "5C", "5C", "ALL", "ALL", "5C", "ALL", "ALL", 
                               "5C", "KMA", "KMA", "5C", "5C", "KMA", "KMA", "ALL", "ALL", 
                               "5C", "ALL", "5C", "KMA", "5C", "ALL", "ALL", "ALL", "5C", 
                               "ALL", "ALL", "5C", "5C", "KMA", "5C", "5C", "5C", "KMA", 
                               "5C", "ALL", "KMA", "KMA", "ALL", "KMA", "5C", "ALL", "ALL", 
                               "KMA", "ALL", "ALL", "KMA", "5C", "ALL", "5C", "ALL", "KMA", 
                               "KMA", "5C", "5C", "5C", "ALL", "5C", "KMA", "KMA", "ALL", 
                               "ALL", "KMA", "KMA", "ALL", "ALL", "5C", "5C", "ALL", "5C", 
                               "KMA", "5C", "5C", "KMA", "5C", "KMA", "5C", "KMA", "ALL", 
                               "5C", "5C", "5C", "ALL", "5C", "ALL", "ALL", "5C", "KMA", 
                               "5C", "KMA", "KMA", "5C", "KMA", "5C", "KMA", "5C", "ALL", 
                               "5C", "ALL", "5C", "5C", "5C", "KMA", "ALL", "KMA", "5C", 
                               "ALL", "ALL", "ALL", "ALL", "ALL", "5C", "KMA", "ALL", "ALL", 
                               "KMA", "KMA", "KMA", "KMA", "KMA", "ALL", "5C", "KMA"), vesicles = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                              1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                                                              1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                              1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                              1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                              2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                              2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                              1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                              1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                              1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                              1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("20K", 
                                                                                                                                                                                  "120K"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   -150L))
```

Comment: The easy answer would seem to be the `gghighlight` package.

Comment: Hi Paul, could you provide a code for this? Thanks

Comment: no, but I have provided a `ggplot2` answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been a fun learning experience for me, so is likely to be unoptimised:

```
# store your existing plot to an object
p <- ggplot(b, aes(y = conc_e5, x = size)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = cohort, fill = cohort),shape = 21, size = 4, stroke = 1) +
  geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs"),
              se = FALSE, size = 2, aes(color = cohort, fill = cohort)) +
  facet_wrap(~ vesicles) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 400))

# use ggplot2's helper function to extract the layer data 
# (note - i = 2 becuase the geom_smooth is the second layer added)
pld <- layer_data(p, i = 2)
# get the maximum per panel (facet) and group (cohort)
maxes <- pld |> group_by(group, PANEL) |> slice_max(y) |> rename(cohort = group, vesicles = PANEL)
# rename the factor levels to match
levels(maxes$vesicles) <- c("20K","120K")

# plot the combined plot
p + 
  geom_point(data = maxes, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_text(data = maxes, aes(x = x, y = y + 2, label = x))
```

gives:
[image]

You can tidy up the aesthetics from there.
(note: image generated using erroneous `label = y` instead of `x`.  code has been updated but image not re-generated).

Comment: @cmirian I've just realised I added the `y` coord to the text not the `x` - sorry!  Should be trivial to change the `label =`.

Answer (score -2):

Apply the `mgcv::gam()` function to the data and save the maximum values for each cohort. Then add these to your existing `ggplot` object, like one would do when highlighting outliers:

```
outliers <- gapminder %>% 
             filter(gdpPercap >= 59000)
gapminder %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = lifeExp, y = gdpPercap)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_point(data = outliers, 
             aes(x = lifeExp, y = gdpPercap), 
             color = 'red')
```

Example code adapted from https://cmdlinetips.com/2019/05/how-to-highlight-select-data-points-with-ggplot2-in-r/

Comment: As the OP provided their sample data, this answer would probably be improved by making use of it and demonstrating the output.